# Heuristic for sliding tile problem

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

The idea is to move all of the right elements into the left and the left into the right with an empty space in the middle. The elements can either jump over one or two pieces into an empty space.

```
LLL[ ]RRR
```

I'm trying to think of a heuristic for this task. Is the heuristic meant to aid in finding a possible solution, or actually return a number of moves as the solution? How would I express such a heuristic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are a bit confused about what a heuristic is.

A rough definition is "a simplifying assumption" or "a decent guess"

For example, let's say you have to put together a basketball team, and you have fact sheets on people who want to play that list their contact info, birth date, and height.  You could hold tryouts where you test each candidate's specific skills; that would require bringing in all the candidates, though, and that could take a long time.  You use a heuristic to narrow the search -- only call people who are at least 6'2" tall.  This might ignore some great basketball players, but it's a pretty decent guess.

Another example of a heuristic: you are trying to use the smallest number of coins to pay a bill.  The heuristic (a simplifying approach) is to pick the coin with the biggest value (which is less than the remaining bill) first, subtract the value from the bill, and repeat.  This is not guaranteed to work every time, but it'll get you to the right neighborhood most of the time.

A heuristic for your problem might be "never move Ls to the right, and never move Rs to the left" -- it narrows the "search space" of all possible moves by eliminating some of the possibilities from the outset.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a heuristic or an algorithm? A heuristic may or may not solve a given problem. It is really just intended to point you in the direction that the solution probably lies in. An algorithm really should solve a given problem.

Comment: I'm looking for heuristic for this, I was thinking about using the amount of elements that are correct compared to the goal state but don't really know how to express it as a formula or in some structural way.

Comment: So you want a criteria to evaluate potential moves?

Comment: More like a way to intelligently select the nodes that are closest to the goal state without being informed on which nodes fail to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic is generally a "hint" which usually (but not always) will guide your procedure to the correct direction. Using heuristics speeds up your procedures (your algorithms), again, **usually**, but not always. It's like an "advice" to the algorithm which is correct more often than not.

I'm not sure what you are looking for, as the description is a little vague. If you want the algorithm, you will need to study what effect a particular move will have to the current situation and a way to step forward for all possible moves each time, in effect traversing a tree of states (ie. states that will evolve if you make a particular sequence of moves).

You can also see that it possibly matters **how close** the current position is to what you want to achieve (your desired final position).So instead of calculating all the possible paths from your initial state until you find the final state, you can guide your algorithm based on the heuristic "how close is the current state to the desired one" and only traverse a part of the tree.